# Invalid formula: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/facebook/homebrew-fb/buck.rb

Tags: reactjs, react-native, facebook, homebrew, apple-m1

I ran the brew command to install Facebook homebrew tap. I have a M1 Apple Silicon Chipset and use a terminal under Rosetta for brew commands.

```
brew tap facebook/fb
```

I got the error message:

```sh
==> Tapping facebook/fb
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/facebook/homebrew-fb'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 46, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (46/46), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (33/33), done.
remote: Total 333 (delta 27), reused 24 (delta 13), pack-reused 287
Receiving objects: 100% (333/333), 5.44 MiB | 9.18 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (179/179), done.
Error: Invalid formula: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/facebook/homebrew-fb/buck.rb
buck: Calling depends_on :java is disabled! Use "depends_on "openjdk@11", "depends_on "openjdk@8" or "depends_on "openjdk" instead.
Please report this issue to the facebook/fb tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core), or even better, submit a PR to fix it:
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/facebook/homebrew-fb/buck.rb:19

Warning: Calling depends_on :osxfuse is deprecated! There is no replacement.
Please report this issue to the facebook/fb tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/facebook/homebrew-fb/xar.rb:8

Error: Cannot tap facebook/fb: invalid syntax in tap!
```

I searched for the facebook/fb tap on Google, I found a GitHib repo but reporting errors is unactivated: https://github.com/facebook/homebrew-fb

Comment: Workaround: fork the repository, change the java dependency to: depends_on "openjdk@8", then issue: brew tap <your repo>/fb

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution you can do is fork the [Facebook/FB](https://github.com/facebook/homebrew-fb) repository into your GitHub account then change the 19th line in buck.rb file. It should be like this:

**old one:**  depends_on java: "1.8"

**new one:**  depends_on "openjdk@8"

The reason we do this Buck still relies on Java 8.
After you do this you can simply open your terminal and write:

```
brew tap {yourGithubAccountName}/homebrew-fb
```

then

```
brew install buck
```