# brew tap facebook/fb results in Fetching error

Tags: macos, homebrew, buck

I try to update Homebrew as usual. Recently when I issue the command `brew update`, the following error occurs:

> Error: Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/facebook/homebrew-fb failed!

The Tap is associated with the software `Buck`, which I need for development.

I further investigate the issue by following the [installation instruction](https://buck.build/setup/getting_started.html) in the Buck official website, I issue the command again:

```
% brew tap facebook/fb
==> Unshallowing facebook/fb
fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/master
Error: Failure while executing; `git fetch --unshallow` exited with 128.
```

Apparently, the Git source has problems. I try to "untap" it:

```
% brew untap facebook/fb
Error: Refusing to untap facebook/fb because it contains the following installed formulae or casks:
buck
```

No luck. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65399729/invalid-formula-usr-local-homebrew-library-taps-facebook-homebrew-fb-buck-rb

Comment: But seems like it's back https://github.com/facebook/idb/issues/646#issuecomment-897588288

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This error is the result of Facebook renaming the branch `master` to `main`.

To fix this, first change into Homebrew's local tap folder:

```
cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/facebook/homebrew-fb
```

Then, run the following Git commands to update the local repo:

```
git branch --unset-upstream
git config remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/main:refs/remotes/origin/main'
git fetch --prune origin
git branch -m main
git branch -u origin/main
git remote set-head origin -a
```

Finally, remove the no longer needed `master` ref (optional):

```
rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/master
```

That's it, you should now be able to successfully run `brew update`.

Comment: really helpful, thx